# Threads and observer pattern. How can i make a thread notify all of the other threads and execute a certain method/thing?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, observer-pattern

Hy .I have a client server app .the server listens on some port and for each client generates a thread that manages it.this is based on sockets and is similar to [this](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/216.html) but the client conects when the Swing interface starts, it calls a method from time to time that sends inf to the server and on close , it closes the stream and socket.The server thread stays awake until the client socket leaves ,and listens to requests.

What i am trying to do is .When a client does something from the interface(pushes a button), to notify all the other clients and i`m stuck.how do i do that.I have to do this by using observer pattern, and i have no idea to use it in this context.how do i notify all the treads an how will they notify the other clients ?

Any sugestion egen though is not about the observer pattern are well received.Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of notifying a thread (which is not simple to do and not needed IMHO), you should have an object on the server which represents each client (if you don't already). Keep a collection of these.  When a client needs to notify all the other clients it can call a method on each of the other objects representing the clients. This can be done using the Observer pattern.

Comment: you sugested that i use Observer on the threads,if i got it wright.But  beeing based on sockets what can i do to notify the client using the socket?

Comment: Your notify method for each client would write something to the client's socket. What it writes is up to you.

Comment: what i was thinking about is that beside the basic 2 communication channels that i call , the client writes first the server waits and receives ,then sends something back.but i would need a different imput stream for the client to wait for the server notification  an a different one for the server to send on  wright ?

Answer (score 1):

Well assume your client sends a notify to the server. The server acts as the subject or in other words holds the observed object. Now every client will register as listener to this server object and gets notified over the socket connection as Observer.

Is that your question?

Comment: i have a server that creates thread per client connected and designates the work to the thread.How can a client notify all the other clients , if he send the request to the thread which doesn`t know about the Server class who can call a method on all active threads. the first answer sugested that i use Observer on the threads,if i got it wright.But  beeing based on sockets what can i do to notify the client using the socket?